# to make a parameter that changes depend on a variable

Tags: dependencies

my question; how can i make a parameter list that is changing depends on one of the decision variable.  i tried something as constraint. pyomo just used initial values to calculate parameter list. I want to learn is it posible to make a parameter that changes depend on all changing of a decision variable.

if i ask on the following example, how can i depend model.y to the variable all changing of model.x?

```
#3)SETS OR PARAMETERS
S=[1,2,3]
X={1:[1,2,3,4,5],2:[4,5,6,7,8],3:[7,8,9,10,11]}
Y={1:10,2:11,3:12}

#4) DECISION VARIABLES
model.S=Set(initialize=S)
model.x=Var(model.S, within=X, initialize=0)
model.y=Param(model.S, initialize=Y)

#5) EXPRESSIONS THAT WILL USE TO WRITE OBJECTION AND CONSTRAINTS
def func_1(model, s):
    if value(model.x[s]) <= 3:
        return model.x[s]**2 + model.y[s]
    else:
        return model.x[s] + model.y[s]

def obj_rule(model):
    return sum(func_1(model, s) for s in model.S)

def cons_1(model,s):
    return model.x[s]+model.y[s]<=20

def cons_2(model):
    return sum(model.x[s]  for s in model.S)<=16

def cons_3(model,s):
    if value(model.x[s])==1:
        return (model.y[s]==15)
    else: 
        return Constraint.Skip


#6) OBJECTIONS
model.ObJ = Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=maximize)

#7) CONSTRAINTS
model.Cons_1=Constraint(model.S, rule=cons_1)
model.Cons_2=Constraint(rule=cons_2)
model.Cons_3=Constraint(model.S, rule=cons_3)
```